# Visual Studio Debugger extensibility - How to follow VS Debugger source file path redirections?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, vsx, visual-studio-debugging, envdte

I'm writing a VS extension that needs to know the full path of the file the user is currently debugging, and I want to support the scenario where the source path written in the pdb is not correct, and the user is prompted to find the file elsewhere.

If I do the following:

1) Debug a DLL whose PDB points at code file at location A

2) Move the code file to different location, B

3) When prompted with the Open File dialog, direct the debugger to locate the code at location B

The file is then opened, and it seems Visual Studio "remembers" this redirection and will know to look for the file in location B even after I restart it.

My problem is, that the IDebugStackFrame2/EnvDTE.StackFrame objects both give me the old, incorrect path for the code file - and I want the correct one so I can read the source from it!  Does Visual Studio expose this indirection table in any way?

How can I get the text of the source file?

P.S. I tried to use the VsShellUtilities.OpenDocument method with the old, incorrect path, but it throws a file not found method..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply can't be done..........

Answer (score 0):

From #2, are you also recompiling?  The PDB itself has the path info to the source, you can look at that with a hex editor.  I don't think you can change the path to the source file, once the debugger has gotten a hold of the PDB and whatever path is specified there.

Comment: Hi, sorry, perhaps I wasn't clear enough in my question - I know the pdb has the path to the source file, and I know how to read the pdb programmatically. What I don't know, is how to get the path from Visual Studio, in the scenario where the code file was not found in the path that was taken from the pdb, and the user was prompted to find the source file himself. I'm not recompiling, I'm just moving the file to a different place to simulate the situation where Visual Studio cannot find the file in the path that was written in the pdb.

Comment: Right, many thanks for your clarification (sorry my confusion).  Regarding the user-specified path, I could never get that to work, I just use that path from the Visual Studio dialog to copy the source files to, but changing the path doesn't seem to work.  Not sure if I'm doing something wrong, or if Visual Studio has a problem in this area.

Comment: Not sure what's wrong there - It works fine for me in VS2008 and VS2010.

Comment: Hmmmmm, must be "operator error" again here... I must revisit this feature, though it's possible I tried it on a stupidly large solution file, where certain parts of VS don't work / are flaky.